# Modifying key-value into an object with name-value pair of different objects

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

I have the object coming in from server as shown below :-

```js
[
    { 
        "gender": {
            "male": 25,
            "female": 22
        },
        "population": {
            "pop_under": -23 ,
            "pop_over": 10,
        }
    }
]
```

I want to extract the key as `name`and value as `value` for above object which after modification looks like this :-

```js
[
   {
       gender : [
           {
               name : "male",
               value : 25
           }, 
           {
               name : "female",
               value : 22
           }
       ], 
       population : [
           {
               name: "pop_under" , 
               value : "-23"
           }, 
           {
               name: "pop_over" , 
               value : "10"
           }
       ]
   } 
]
```

How can perform said modification? And is it useful to use `lodash`package for this ?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: There are seriously HUNDREDS of dupes of this at SO

Answer (score 1):

You can user `reducer` for creating new object and `Object.keys` for looping object fields:

```
const newData = data.reduce((acc,rec) => {
  return [...acc, Object.keys(rec).reduce((iacc,irec)=>{
    return {...iacc, 
             [irec]: (Object.keys(rec[irec]).map((item)=>{
               return {name: item, value: rec[irec][item]}
             }))
           } 
  },{})]
}, [])
```

See full example in the playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s528735

Answer (score 1):

Using .map and Object.keys method.

```
let result =[];
data.forEach(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>{ 
      let response = Object.
                         keys(obj[key]).
                         map(property=> (
                                          {
                                            name: `${property}`, 
                                            value:obj[key][property]
                                          }
                                        )
                            );
     result.push({[key]:response});
    });
});
console.log(result);
```